# Performance of calling gameObject.SetActive(true) when game object is already active?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there any performance concern around calling `MyAlreadyActiveGameObject.SetActive(true)` a ton, e.g., once per frame?

Put another way, is it ever worth pulling a `gameObject.active` check upwards? Or caching/checking an `_alreadyActive`?

Comment: This is *definitely* a case of premature optimization. If you're worried about it though, create a test case and analyze the results.

Comment: Good question. This question doesn't seem clearly like premature optimization to me.  It's a single foundational function within Unity, not a complex piece of code in your software. Seems like a function that is worth investing a few minutes into so you have an understanding of it.

Creating a test case would probably be premature optimization though.

Comment: So did anyone run the test?

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about this, you could always do a basic if-check on the same line.

```
if(!myObject.activeSelf) myObject.SetActive(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, try the simple thing first and see if it works. Sometimes it's worth focusing on optimization, but you should check if it's necessary effort. Unity's built-in profiling tools can give you an estimate on how long each operation is taking in each frame.

> Is there any performance concern around calling `MyAlreadyActiveGameObject.SetActive(true)` a ton, e.g., once per frame?

It does take time, but not much. If you're doing this hundreds or thousands of times per frame, it might be worth worrying about. Up until then, the concern should be negligible.

If you are worried about performance for a large number of objects, you can look into pausing expensive behaviors for objects which are far away, out of view, etc.

Comment: If an object is very complicated and has many children then the act of calling SetActive can be very expensive. It can take many seconds to activate an object.

Comment: @off99555 That sounds like a very unusual example. My answer focused on more common scenarios.